# React Navigation, reset stack without redirecting

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Is it possible to reset the navigation stack without redirecting?

I tried the resetAction, but I don't want it to redirect to homepage. I just want to clear the stack history

```
        const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "Home" })]
        });
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stay on the current route and clear the history, replace "Home" in your code above with your current route name. It will reload the current route. If you want Home to stay as your root er... route, add your current route to the actions array and change index to 1